# how to ignore special row in the collect_list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like below.

```
|    COLUMN A|            COLUMN b|
|        Case|          1111111111|
|     Rectype|                ABCD|
|         Key|   UMUM_REF_ID=A1234|
|  UMSV ERROR|    UNITS_ALLOW must|
|  NTNB ERROR|       GGGGGGG Value|
|        Case|          2222222222|
|     Rectype|                ABCD|
|         Key|   UMUM_REF_ID=B8765|
|  UMSV ERROR|    UNITS_ALLOW must|
|  NTNB ERROR|       Invalid Value|
```

I want to add new column "C".
C is the collect_list "Case", "Rectype", "key", "UMSV ERROR" and "NTNB ERRO" in A.

My code is

```
val window = Window.rowsBetween(0,4)
val begin = rddDF.withColumn("C", collect_list( $"value").over( window)).where( $"A" like  "Case")
begin.show()
```

It works well.

Now,  I want to get the collect_list again but ignore the "NTNB ERROR" where its value in column b is "Invalid Value".
What should I do please?

Comment: Why don't you filter out those rows with the condition that doesn't satisfy your requirements ?

Comment: Yes, filter the column C is a way.But I want to know whether I can filter with collect_list.

Comment: @Robin: Can you verify the answer and post if there are any questions.